# Add audio to an MP4 in Java (JDK) without FFmpeg

Tags: java, audio, video, mp4

I am currently working on a project in Java, where I have to combine several pictures to an MP4 file and also add audio track to this file (as WAV or MP3).

I have managed to create an MP4 file from the images using [**JCodec**](http://jcodec.org/). I chose this library because if I should ever want this to run on Android, this library is compatible there.

I tried using the [**MP4 Parser**](https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser) but it only accepts `AAC/M4A` files. But I want this to work with `WAV` files or `MP3`.
All other useful libraries I found so far use FFmpeg in some way. I do not want the people using the program having to install the FFMPEG command line tool which I'd then call from Java.

So what I want to know is,

- Is there a way of adding audio to an MP4 file in Java without using FFmpeg, or at least using it in some way where I don't have to install the command line tool?
- If there is, do I have to use AAC/M4A files? If yes, then I'd also like to know how to convert a WAV or MP3 file to AAC/M4A in Java. Is there a good library for doing the job? I've been stuck at this point for about a week now and I hope this thread will lead to some more useful result.

I hope someone will be able to help,
I wish you a happy day, whether you can help or not.

Bye for now,
Robbe.

Comment: Hi, have you considered sending it to a remote server and do the operation over there?

Comment: Well, I haven't. But as my upload speed is awful, I don't know if I'd want to sit through uploading several pictures and then downloading an mp4...

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: No, I used FFMPEG in the end.

Answer (score -1):

using this code you can add .wav and other supported formats by jdk to your java code

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
```

use try catch or throws method
here i used try catch method

```
public class Music {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        try{
            File file = new File("--file location--");
            AudioInputStream audioStream =AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audioStream);

            clip.start();

            Thread.sleep(s*1000); // s = time in seconds

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
            System.out.println("File Not Supported");
         }

    }
}
```

[Click here to open my github repository AddingAudioToJava](https://github.com/Ramcharantejpaka/AddingAudioToJava.git)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, but this wasn't really the question unfortunately.